# Model with property that can be an any value type

Tags: c#, .net, angular, api, generics

I have a controller method that gets the FilterState model.
That model contains a list of Filter models, that contains Value property, which can be any of a value type (int, string, datetime etc).
How I can write this class and determine the property type that came to me from front end?

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<GridResultViewModel<ItemGridViewModel>> GetFiltered(int modelId, 
  [FromQuery] FilterState filterState)
{
   ...
}

public class FilterState
{
   public int Skip { get; set; }
   public int Take { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
}

public class Filter
{
   public string Operator { get; set; }
   public string Field { get; set; }
   public ??? Value { get; set; } // this can be string, int, datetime etc.
}
```

If I made Value property as object or dynamic type, is always null.
I'm using Angular 11 on frontend.

Comment: I think the only option here is to set type to `string` and then, probably based on another property, try to parse to specific type

Answer (score 0):

```
        public string Value { get; set; } = "str12";

        object CheckType(string value)
        {
            return
                int.TryParse(value, out int intVal) ? intVal :
                DateTime.TryParse(value, out DateTime datetimeVal) ? datetimeVal :
                value;
        }

        var result = CheckType(Value);
        if (result is int)
        {
            
        }
        if (result is string)
        {

        }
```